# What is the difference from the meet.one and lynx eos wallet for android?

Tags: wallet, lynx-wallet, meet.one-wallet, android

What are the pros and cons of meet.one and lynx eos wallet? Also who created them and from which country? Is their wallet code open source?

Comment: you get your account info on the main net. There you also check the history of your account activity.Who creates your account your ram info everything is there.

Comment: Please also consider the EOS REACH Android app which is open source: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.memtrip.eosreach